# D3.js - load csv file from chrome

Tags: csv, d3.js, cross-domain, dc.js

I 've got a webProject with dc.js (d3.js+crossfilter.js) and ndx.csv file. When i run project into chrome from visual studio, everythings is Ok. Now after build project and copy in other computers, Run that.
**The problem is here**. When i try to run webProject [html file] in other computers with ***Chrome***, this browser has error "*XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/9901/Desktop/WebSite1/ndx.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.*" I search about this problem, but haven't found solution.
Hints:

1. I want just use browser **"Chrome Portable"**, Otherwise no problrm with IE and FireFox
2. My addressbar in run: "***file:///C:/Users/User-1/Desktop/WebSite1/Index.html***".
3. I don't have web server in ***other computers***.

Comment: generally you will need a web server to test dc.js apps. one simple web server is [built into python](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python), maybe you can use that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved my problem:

1. Create shortcut and open properties of that.
2. add ***--allow-file-access-from-files*** to end of target field's string.

Comment: can you provide some screen shot or details ? i have the same problem and dont understang how to do this

Comment: Just start Chrome with command and arg: `C:\PathTo\Chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files` for Windows and `open -a "Google Chrome" -n --args --allow-file-access-from-files` for macOS. (simple but unsafe)

Answer (score 5):

If you're not married to Chrome, you can use Firefox. It works by default.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue before and I resolved it with an easy approach.
You can't get data from .csv file because host and protocol are different.

To fix this issue, you should run a simple web server.
The following example would work.

> npm install -g http-server
>
> http-server

Comment: Wonderful! It works well for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to use a local web server, you can install the CORS extensionfrom the chrome web store.

1. Go to https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi
2. Install the CORS extension
3. Enable the extension (you can see its icon next to the address bar)
4. Open you html file

Comment: I use portable chrome.

Comment: I have added and enabled the extension but the solution is not working.